# Moving parts of navbar down when window become small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my navbar has 4 links and a brand logo in the middle, (2 links on each side). I'm using bootstrap so what I want is for when the screen is small, then for the links to go beneath the brand. So instead of 2 links, then brand, then 2 links all on one line, I'd have the brand, then on the next line in the center underneath, the 4 links. But I don't know how to do this? Here's a fiddle of what I have so far. Note: On my laptop, I can't make the fiddle for this to md size (>992 px)

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar" class="li flex-container nav">
    <a class="nav-link flex-item col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3" href="#">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item col-md-2 col-sm-3 " href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a class="hplogo-a flex-item col-md-2 col-sm-12" href=""><img id="logo" src="http://www.morushsoccer.com/_uploads/563cff4e616e743953300000/Adidas.png" alt=""></a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item col-md-2 col-sm-3" href="#">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
    <a class="nav-link flex-item col-md-2 col-sm-3" href="#">BLOG</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color: #333;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin:0px;

}

.nav{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 z-index: 2;

}

.resize-anchor{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.hplogo-a{
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

a:hover{
  color:#D1946F;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link{
  color:#D1946F;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navlink, .hplogo-a{
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.nav-link{
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Calibri;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 line-height: 26.4px;
 padding:0px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
img{
  width:100%
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b6ks4mfk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to have two logos in the html code, each with a different class. Then use media queries and the display property (hide/initial/block, etc) to display or hide the logos according to the size of the screen.

Comment: I also am having an issue with moving an image behind the navbar/overlapping the navbar and image. Before I added bootstrap I used position: absolute, but if i put that now it messes up the navbar.